# C++ Template class member function that returns the same template class data type

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to make a proof-of-concept class template that makes a 2D vector. I'm trying to make a member function that returns a "flipped" version of the vector were x becomes y and vice versa. I want the function to return the Vector2 template class data type. This is my syntax:

Class:

```
template<class T>
class Vector2
{
private:
    T m_x;
    T m_y;
public:
    Vector2();
    Vector2(const T& x, const T& y);
    T getX();
    T getY();
    void setX(const T& x);
    void setY(const T& y);
    template <class U> friend Vector2<U> getFlippedCopy();
};
```

The syntax for the flip function:

```
template <class T>
Vector2<T> Vector2<T>::getFlippedCopy()
{
    Vector2<T> vectorCopy;
    vectorCopy.setX(m_y);
    vectorCopy.setY(m_x);
    return vectorCopy;
}
```

However, I get an error:

```
classes.hpp:51:12: error: no declaration matches ‘Vector2<T> Vector2<T>::getFlippedCopy()’
   51 | Vector2<T> Vector2<T>::getFlippedCopy()
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
classes.hpp:51:12: note: no functions named ‘Vector2<T> Vector2<T>::getFlippedCopy()’
classes.hpp:4:7: note: ‘class Vector2<T>’ defined here
    4 | class Vector2
      |       ^~~~~~~
```

Also, where is a good resource to properly learn templates and all their complexities? I find lots of YouTube videos don't go beyond the basics or skim over complicated stuff...

Comment: You say you're trying to make a member function, but you're defining a `friend` function. Both might work... Which would you like?

Comment: `friend`s are not members. `getFlippedCopy` is now a free function in the same namespace as `Vector2`. Since you seem to want a member function (looking at the implementation), drop `friend` keyword.

Comment: When I drop the friend it still errors with basically the same error message saying no declaration matches...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to define a member function named `getFlippedCopy` but you haven't declared such a function.

I suspect that you've made a mistake by instead declaring a free `friend` function with the same name. I suggest making it a member function instead, which should then be `const` qualified:

```cpp
template<class T>
class Vector2 {
    //...
    // note: not a function template:
    Vector2 getFlippedCopy() const;
};

template <class T>
Vector2<T> Vector2<T>::getFlippedCopy() const {
    Vector2<T> vectorCopy;
    vectorCopy.setX(m_y);
    vectorCopy.setY(m_x);
    return vectorCopy;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that and got a different error `/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccAyllaP.o: in function `Vector2<float>::getFlippedCopy()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7Vector2IfE14getFlippedCopyEv[_ZN7Vector2IfE14getFlippedCopyEv]+0x27): undefined reference to `Vector2<float>::Vector2()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` when I tried to call it from main.cpp.

Comment: @WillDenny That's an unrelated error.  You need to implement the default constructor too. In your question, you've only declared it. The same goes for the member functions `setX` and `setY`. You've only shown us declarations and they all need to be implemented.

Comment: I do apologise, you're right that's unrelated - I hadn't defined the default constructor. It now works, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your function, `getFlippedCopy()`, does 2 things:

- creates a copy
- flips x and y

If you decouple the two steps, it'll be easier.

You can simply add a copy ctor and a `flip()` method:

```
Vector2(const Vector2& other)
: m_x(other.m_x), m_y(other.m_y) {}

void flip() { std::swap(x, y); }
```

Then, if you want a helper that does copy-and-flip:

```
// inside Vector's definition
Vector2 getFlippedCopy() const
{
    Vector2 ret(*this);
    ret.flip();
}
```

Also, don't do `getX()` and `setX()`: if you have both, that means the member should be public.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback. I still get an error - now from my main function saying the declaration is not recognised: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccAyllaP.o: in function `Vector2<float>::getFlippedCopy()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7Vector2IfE14getFlippedCopyEv[_ZN7Vector2IfE14getFlippedCopyEv]+0x27): undefined reference to `Vector2<float>::Vector2()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @WillDenny You likely didn't define default ctor: `Vector2() {}` inside the class _or_ `template<typename T> Vector2::Vector2() {}` outside (not both).

Comment: Sorry I hadn't defined the default constructor which caused the error! Thanks!